# ServiceNotFoundException Symfony 3.3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony3.x

In a Symfony 3.3 Project I defined a class at

```
../AppBundle/Helper/ProgramHelper
```

like this

```
class ProgramHelper implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;
    protected $em;
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

In services.yml I added it like this

```
services:
    ...
    app.helper.program_helper:
        class: AppBundle\Helper\ProgramHelper
        tags:
             - { name: app.helper, alias: 'container_aware' }
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```

Now - trying to access the class from a controller like

```
$ph = $this->get('app.helper.program_helper');
```

results in this error

```
ServiceNotFoundException
You have requested a non-existent service "app.helper.program_helper".
```

Any hint on the issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Please make sure debug mode is enabled, if production mode enabled then clear cache then refresh your page

Comment: @Manmohan I did clear the cache before using cache:clear -e dev - I run the app on the URL ../app_dev.php/... which should put me in dev mode right? So - cache does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: Add public: true to the service definition.  Services are now private by default which means that you can no longer access them via get.  bin/console debug:container will confirm the service is available.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you! That was the problem. If you post it as an answere you get the tick :-)

Comment: It's not really much of an answer.  Unless this is a big legacy project then you should consider upgrading to at least 3.4 (3.3 is no longer supported) and spend a bit of time reviewing the service container portion of the docs.  Lots and lots of changes on how to use services.

Comment: @Cerad well - it solved my problem. So thanks. I will consider upgrading to 3.4

Comment: Why you bother creating service definitions? Autowiring works great in modern Sf.

Answer (score 4):

@Cerad answered the question - thank you!

> Add public: true to the service definition. Services are now private
>   by default which means that you can no longer access them via get.
>   bin/console debug:container will confirm the service is available.